# I cant call a class method in Python; AttributeError: 'check_class' object has no attribute 'check_1'

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, recursion

I want to check if the games have numbers in a particular key?

But i cant call the the class method check_1(), can you help me out?
It gives me 'check_class' object has no attribute 'check_1'.

And do you have a idea how i can avoid the global variabel and the global fuction for the recursion, because its bad practice?

I am thankful for every suggestion to optimize the code, i am relatively new to programing.

```
from queue import Empty

class check_class :
    
    def __init__(self, dict1={}, dict2={}, dict3={}, dict4={}, dict5={}, dict6={}, dict7={}, dict8={}, dict9={}, dict10={}, dict11={}, dict12={}, dictionary_of_games ={}):
        self.dict1 = dict1
        self.dict2 = dict2
        self.dict3 = dict3
        self.dict4 = dict4
        self.dict5 = dict5
        self.dict6 = dict6
        self.dict7 = dict7
        self.dict8 = dict8
        self.dict9 = dict9
        self.dict10 = dict10
        self.dict11 = dict11
        self.dict12 = dict12
        self.dictionary_of_games = dictionary_of_games

        dictionary_of_games = [
        self.dict1,
        self.dict2,
        self.dict3,
        self.dict4,
        self.dict5,
        self.dict6,
        self.dict7,
        self.dict8,
        self.dict9,
        self.dict10,
        self.dict11,
        self.dict12
        ]

    global played_games_of_the_day
    played_games_of_the_day =[]

    global check_1
    def check_1(self, **kwargs):
        hht = kwargs.get("halbzeit_h_tore")
        hat = kwargs.get("halbzeit_a_tore")
        c = 1
        if hht == "-" and hat == "-":
            played_games_of_the_day.append(0)
            c += 1
            return check_1(self, self.dictionary_of_games[c])
        elif int(hht) == int and int(hat) == int :
            c += 1
            played_games_of_the_day.append(1)
            return check_1(self, self.dictionary_of_games[c])
        #if dict empty pass#
        elif Empty:
            pass
        
        for i in played_games_of_the_day:
            if all(x==0 for x in played_games_of_the_day):
                print("all zero")
            elif all(x==1 for x in played_games_of_the_day):
                print("all one")

a = {0: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Fr', 'd_u': '13.08.2021 20:30', 'team1': 'Borussia M´gladbach', 'team2': 'Bayern München', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
     1: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'Arminia Bielefeld', 'team2': 'SC Freiburg', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
     2: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfL Wolfsburg', 'team2': 'VfL Bochum', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
     3: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FC Augsburg', 'team2': 'TSG Hoffenheim', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '4', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
     4: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfB Stuttgart', 'team2': 'Greuther Fürth', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
     5: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': '1. FC Union Berlin', 'team2': 'Bayer Leverkusen', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
     6: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 18:30', 'team1': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'team2': 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '3', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
     7: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FSV Mainz 05', 'team2': 'RB Leipzig', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
     8: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 17:30', 'team1': '1. FC Köln', 'team2': 'Hertha BSC Berlin', 'h_tore': '3', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}}

b = check_class(a)
b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0])
```

I'm getting an `AttributeError`: 'check_class' object has no attribute 'check_1'

Comment: What do you mean, you can't call the method?

Comment: b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0]) , isnt callable  , it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, "it does not work" is not an acceptable problem description. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Like i  said i cant call the method with: b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0]). I have a other class in my prog where it works fine, can it have samothing to do with making the function global?

Comment: Don't know, you did not tell us what the problem is.

Comment: And it would be good to know why its downvoted, so i dont make the same mistake asking next time.

Comment: Because you did not follow what's in the link I gave you.

Comment: I will read now through it, this is what i get on that call like I edited above: 'check_class' object has no attribute 'check_1'

Comment: `check_1` doesn't seem to be a class method. I would honestly be surprised if you knew what a class method in python is, given that you're new to programming. As a whole, the code has several mistakes and I would recommend you to either follow a different tutorial or, if you're not following any, take a course for newbies, before trying to code anything complex on your own.

Comment: I took a tutorial cours, i know its not the best coding. How should I call it a class function?

Comment: In any case, remove the two lines where it says `global xxxxxx`. That most probably doesn't do what you think it does, and it's not needed in your code.

Comment: If i do that i cant use played_games_of_the_day in the check_1 function and i cant use the recursion in the function.

Comment: And if you don't you can't even use `check_1` at all... to call a method of a class from within, or get an attribute of it, you need to use `self`. `self.check_1()` can call `check_1` from inside `check_class`.

Comment: Object oriented programming on python is a little more advance topic which is why I recommended you to take either a different course or a more advanced one.

Comment: Yes now this part works, I know but this is just practice. I am trying to learn more with this. Like now that global fuction, creats a function i the global scope that isnt callable over the class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `global check_1` before the definition of the function in the class body will create a function in the global scope, not a method.

```
class A:
    global check_1
    def check_1(self):
        print('check_1')
    def check_2(self):    
        print('check_2')
```

Demo:

```
>>> 'check_1' in A.__dict__
False
>>> 'check_2' in A.__dict__
True
>>> check_1
<function __main__.check_1(self)>
>>> A().check_1()
[...]
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'check_1'
>>> A().check_2()
check_2
```

As to why you put `global check_1` there, I have no idea.

Comment: You are right, but how can i make a recursive function without it? If i delete the global of check_1 this line does not work: return check_1(self, self.dictionary_of_games[c]).

Comment: @Fuorb different question. Please make a new post, but with as little code as necessary to show the problem. Start from scratch and make a minimal example class.

Comment: Found it, return self.check_1(self, self.dictionary_of_games[c]), needed to add the self.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your example code has several problems.
You will have to examine the concept of scope a little more.
Note the use of the variable `self.played_games_of_the_day`.
Also the call to the constructor did not set the `dictionary_of_games` - it was always set to an empty dict.

I have corrected your code so that it might theoretically run, but I am not sure what is supposed to do. In so doing I have removed the dicts dict1, dict2, etc. as they were not being used.

In future you should post the errors that python gives you to be more precise about your problem and reduce your problem to a minimal example...

```
from queue import Empty

class Check_class :
    
    def __init__(self, dictionary_of_games):
        self.dictionary_of_games = dictionary_of_games
        self.played_games_of_the_day = []

    def check_1(self):
        for entry in self.dictionary_of_games.values():
            hht = entry.get("halbzeit_h_tore")
            hat = entry.get("halbzeit_a_tore")
            if hht == "-" and hat == "-":
                print(f"{hht} {hat}")
                self.played_games_of_the_day.append(0)
            elif hht.isnumeric() and hat.isnumeric():
                print(f"{hht}:{hat}")
                self.played_games_of_the_day.append(1)
            #if dict empty pass#
            elif Empty:
                pass
        
        if all(x==0 for x in self.played_games_of_the_day):
            print("all zero")
        elif all(x==1 for x in self.played_games_of_the_day):
            print("all one")

a = { 0: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Fr', 'd_u': '13.08.2021 20:30', 'team1': 'Borussia M´gladbach', 'team2': 'Bayern München', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
    1: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'Arminia Bielefeld', 'team2': 'SC Freiburg', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
    2: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfL Wolfsburg', 'team2': 'VfL Bochum', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    3: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FC Augsburg', 'team2': 'TSG Hoffenheim', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '4', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
    4: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfB Stuttgart', 'team2': 'Greuther Fürth', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
    5: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': '1. FC Union Berlin', 'team2': 'Bayer Leverkusen', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
    6: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 18:30', 'team1': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'team2': 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '3', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}, 
    7: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FSV Mainz 05', 'team2': 'RB Leipzig', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '}, 
    8: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 17:30', 'team1': '1. FC Köln', 'team2': 'Hertha BSC Berlin', 'h_tore': '3', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}
    }
    
b = Check_class(a)
b.check_1()
print('Done!')
```

Comment: Thanks i will do the in the future, like i said i am relatively new. What do you mean with specify in the call? Becaus that could be the problem why "b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0])"  KeyError: 0.

Comment: This code still has several problems and wouldn't work. You're passing two arguments to `self.check_1()`, but you only need to pass one. `self` is automatically filled when you execute a method of a class. Also, you probably haven't noticed, but `__init__` has mutable defaults. That can lead to big problems and headaches. It should be fixed too. Also, you've called the argument in the method `dict`. That shadows the `dict` name, any other name would have been fine.

Comment: Yes `b = Check_class(dictionary_of_games = a)` is what I was referring to.
If you just write `b = Check_class(a)` then the constructor does not know what the parameter is supposed to be, as you have only named parameters.
The consequence is that the class instance only has an empty `dictionary_of_games` so that accessing `[0]` produces the key error.

Comment: Need to delete self in : return self.check_1(self, self.dictionary_of_games[c])

Comment: Okay i changed to b = Check_class(dictionary_of_games = a), now: "check_class.check_1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" when i call this : b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0]). Why b.dictionary_of_games[0] two arguments, its one with **kwargs, how am I wrong?

Comment: Look up the use of kwargs. These are keyword-arguments, so you would have to specify the calling parameter as a key-value pair, e.g. `param=value`.
`b.check_1(b.dictionary_of_games[0])` has one positional parameter, but no kw-parameters. I have change the code of `__init__` to no longer use kw-type parameters, so the call `b = Check_class(a)` becomes possible.

Comment: Ok, I have looked over the code, trying to understand what you really want.
I have rewritten it, so that it makes more sense - to me, at least.
Sorry if I haven't managed to read your mind!